# Where are SYS Audit Entries in Windows Event Log?

Tags: oracle, audit, sysdba

I have audit_sys_operations set to true, audit_trail set to DB, have restarted the database since setting them, and have logged in as and performed actions as sysdba. However, I cannot find these entries in the Windows Event Log Viewer. From what I read, they should be under Windows Logs->Application. When looking there, I see nothing with an event id of 34 or a Source containing Oracle.

Am I missing something, or is something perhaps not configured properly?

Comment: If you have audit_trail set to DB, then it's in the DB that your saving audit info. Check Dba_audit_trail. If you want to send to Windows Event Log, change audit_trail to OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audit files get written into the folder audit_file_dest points to.

```
select value from v$parameter where name='audit_file_dest';
```